# how to disable the actionsheet button in ios

Tags: iphone

In my project i have created textfield using actionsheet button.how can i disable the userinterface after first creation.

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex                                                                                                                                                                            
{
        if (buttonIndex==0)
            {  
                text1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x2,y2+3, 300, 25)];
                text1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                text1.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                text1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
                text1.placeholder=@"ENTER HOME LOAN INTEREST";
                [text1 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
                text1.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                text1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                [scrollview addSubview:text1];
                scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+to);
                to+=to;
                y2+=30;
                img6.frame=CGRectMake(0, y2+4, 320, 60);
                y2=y2+62;
                img7.frame=CGRectMake(0, y2+5, 320, 60);
                 y2=y2-62;
            }
           else if (buttonIndex==1)
            {
                text2 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x2, y2+3, 300, 25)];
                text2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                text2.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
                text2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
                text2.placeholder=@"ENTER EDUCATION EXPENSE";
                [text2 setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
                text2.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
                text2.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                [scrollview addSubview:text2];
                               scrollview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height+to);

                 to+=to;

                y2+=30;

                img6.frame=CGRectMake(0, y2+4, 320, 60);
                y2=y2+60;
                img7.frame=CGRectMake(0, y2+5, 320, 60);
                 y2=y2-60;
            }

}
```

how can i prevent user from creating same textfield many time

Comment: How are you invoking the action sheet? I assume from a button or other control. Disable that from within your code above

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if the two textfields are the same, with the exception of the placeholder, and presumably what you do with the value later. You could easily use a single textfield that is accessible as a property in your class. If you are using storyboards, it's possible that you can place the textfield in your storyboard and perhaps set it to 'hidden'.

Once you have a common text field, you can simply set the placeholder text and make the field visible inside the actionsheet delegate method. If there are other differences in the layout, then those too can be handled at this point.

This approach would need a way to hold 'state' so that you know the context of the field later on.  You could manage this by examining the placeholder text, but this would be fragile because the text may change on a whim. A better approach would be to set a tag value e.g. `text2.tag = 1` for home load interest and `text2.tag = 2` for education expense. You can later access the tag value to interpret the context.

Because there is only one field, and because it is accessible by a property, you can later remove the textfield from the superview, or hide it again and use another flag to know that it has been displayed to the user.  Most likely you can check that you have a value for either home loan interest or education expense, in which case, don't show it again.

You can hide/remove/disable the button that invokes the actionsheet from within the actionsheet delegate callback method too, again you will need a property in order to access it.